# Who consider(s) to become

Tags: grammar

I've got a question with regard to an English sentence. 
Can anyone tell me whether the following sentence is correct?

> What are the main prospects and challenges for non-euro area countries
>   who/that consider(s) to become member of the European Banking Union.

So I'm doubting whether I should use who or that and whether consider is written with or without s.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: ... that are considering becoming members of...

Comment: You aren't doubting: you're questioning. This is a common misuse of *doubt* by English learners.

Comment: @tchrist: it's also a common misuse of *doubt* by Indian speakers of English.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't much matter if you use *who* or *that*.

But there are several other mistakes in your sentence, so for the benefit of space I post this as an answer.

The main problem with your sentence (which is a question and deserves a question mark) is that *consider to become member* does not make sense. You can ***be considering membership*** of the EBU, or ***considering becoming a member***. But it is not idiomatic for ***a country to consider to become a member***.

You would in any case need the plural verb *consider* (rather than *considers*) to agree with *countries*.

And *member* either needs an indefinite article -if singular, but to agree with *countries* it really needs to be plural. So in all:

***What are the main prospects and challenges for non-euro-area countries that are considering membership of the European Banking Union ?***

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *considering becoming* something. Moreover, *aspiring* gives a slant that isn't present in *considering*, which is more neutral. Perhaps a smoother wording would be, "... countries that are *considering membership* in the EBU".

Comment: @Théophile Your suggestion is good - apart from your use of "in": it should be "... countries that are considering membership *of* the EBU".

Comment: @TrevorD I think both are fine; in fact, Google Ngrams shows a slight preference for *in*.

Comment: @Théophile I have absolutely no objection to *considering becoming a member of the EBU*, or *considering membership*. But *considering to become a member* is not idiomatic. I take your point about *aspire*.

Comment: @TrevorD I agree. And I will amend my answer,

Comment: @WS2 Looks like we all agree now. :)

Comment: "...membership of the EBU" or "....membership in the EBU"?

Comment: @ab2 Both are idiomatic, but in Britain *membership of* would be the more popular. It may be different in America. Their choice of prepositions can be at variance with ours - but in this case I suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/that_which_who.htm) website will solve your confusion between the words like which, that and who. As far as the word 'consider' is concerned, there won't be 's' because of the plural word "countries". Whenever you have a confusion, just replace the noun with the corresponding pronoun. For example, replace 'countries' with 'they'. Now, which sounds correct: They consider or they considers? Obviously the first one. This is the cheap trick which I use whenever in such kind of a dilemma.

Comment: Unfortunately, _consider_ can't take an infinitive complement with Equi; i.e, *_They consider to join the Union_ is ungrammatical, as @WS2 has pointed out.